# dash ( - ) in where clause with sleep function

Tags: mysql, database, sql-injection, sleep

In MySQL you can pause a result for x seconds with the [`SLEEP` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_sleep).

I understand when you use it like this:

```
SELECT SLEEP(1000);
```

But I recently saw that you can enhance a query in this form:

```
mysql> select * from docs where rev = 1-sleep(4);
```

and it will wait 4 seconds before it returns the results in comparison to

```
mysql> select * from docs where rev = 1;
```

Why is this so? Is the dash a form of concatenating functions or something like this? I couldn't find any explanation for this syntax.

---

I reproduced this query using docker

```
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:latest
docker exec -ti some-mysql mysql -uroot -pmy-secret-pw
```

and the following code to create the table (using code from [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6c585/1)) and verify the behavior.

```
CREATE test;
USE test;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docs` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `rev` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`rev`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `docs` (`id`, `rev`, `content`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', 'The earth is flat'),
  ('2', '1', 'One hundred angels can dance on the head of a pin'),
  ('1', '2', 'The earth is flat and rests on a bull\'s horn'),
  ('1', '3', 'The earth is like a ball.');
select * from docs where rev = 1;
select * from docs where rev = 1-sleep(4);
```

Comment: We use something along those lines as minimally invasive but easily identifiable SQL Injection test case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can read in the manual you've linked, `SLEEP` returns 0. So using it in some kind of calculation like `where rev = 1-sleep(4);` triggers the execution of `SLEEP` (as in: waits four seconds). Afterwards, the query is resumed with `where rev = 1-0`, making it equal to `where rev = 1`